# The Monad Challenges - A Missed Generalization

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, monads, state-monad

I'm going through [*The Monad Challenges*](http://mightybyte.github.io/monad-challenges/).

At the section [*A Missed Generalization*](http://mightybyte.github.io/monad-challenges/pages/ex4-2.html), I'm supposed to have at least this code (I've removed parts not relevant to the question), where `Gen` looks a lot like the State Monad,

```hs
-- Imports and other stuff that hide Prelude
-- For instance, the do notation is NOT available at this stage of the challenges

type Gen a = Seed -> (a,Seed)

genTwo :: Gen a -> (a -> Gen b) -> Gen b
genTwo g f s = let (a,s') = g s
               in f a s'

mkGen :: a -> Gen a
mkGen a s = (a,s)

generalB :: (a -> b -> c) -> Gen a -> Gen b -> Gen c
-- I've implemented it as follows and it works
generalB f a b s = let (x,s') = a s
                       (y,s'') = b s'
                   in (f x y,s'')
```

The text of the "assignment" reads

> […] you might not have implemented `generalB` in terms of `genTwo`. Go back and look at your `generalB` implementation and if you didn’t write it in terms of `genTwo`, do that now and call it `generalB2`. Doing this should get rid of the state threading between generators.

Is unclear to me what the solution to this should be, especially in view of the fact that the paragraph above doesn't mention `mkGen`. Assuming I'm able to apply `f` to the inside of `a` and `b`, I would still get something of type `c`, which I have to shove in a `Gen`, and I don't see how I can do that without `mkGen` or, alternatively, without using `(,)` explicitly (as I did in the above implementation).

Even assuming that the text implies that I should use `mkGen`, how should I go about it to *get rid of the state threading*?

With some editing I was able to come up with this

```hs
generalB2' f a b = genTwo a (genTwo b . (mkGen .) . f)
```

but I hardly believe this is the intended solution, because it's far from being readable, in my opinion. Also, getting to this form was a bit harder than anything else so far in the challenges, but it was after all just mechanical, so it didn't really pose a difficulty from the point of view of understanding monads, I believe, so I really think I took a wrong turn here, and I'd like some help.

I wonder whether the authors of the challenges hang out here on StackOverflow.

Comment: You can read ``a `genTwo` (\x -> ....`` as "roll the die `a` once, and let `x` be its result". Underneath, the state is threaded automatically, making the code more readable and less error prone (it's easy to revert to an old state by mistake when you thread states around). At the very end, you'll need `mkGen` as you stated (or you'll need to thread state explicitly).

Comment: @chi, I tried going via ``a `genTwo` (\x -> ...``, but didn't get far; I think I get lost _at the very end [...] you'll need to thread state explicitly_ I believe. Specifically I wrote a function which typechecks, ``generalB2 f a b = a `genTwo` (\a' -> b `genTwo` (\b' -> mkGen undefined))``, but then I don't know what to put at the placeholder. Could you give an answer explaining this?

Comment: Oh, I think I got it. The last lambda should be `\b' -> mkGen (f a' b')`.

Comment: Indeed, in a general monad we would have used `generalB2 f a b = a >>= (\a' -> b >>= (\b' -> return (f a' b')))` which is known `liftM2`. Here we instead use the "disguised" definitions, but the shape of the code is the same.

Comment: Yeah, the correspondence was clear to me, and suggested pretty explicitly by the text on the site. I think the problem is that I still find hard to reason about the state monad (despite having never looked at solutions so far), just like I have to go through the "flux" of the states and the values to try understanding the whole picture. As in, I have to see the pipelines, which is a bit hard. Feel free to add the answer, and I'll accept it.

Comment: Actually, I don't think I added anything significant beyond Mark's answer below. If you think some point is missing there, feel free to add an answer yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution is probably close to the intended solution, although you might be able to make it more readable by eta-expanding it. You might even consider writing it using `do` notation, but still use `genTwo` and `mkGen`.

As far as I can tell, `mkGen` is a 'disguised' `return` function, and `genTwo` likewise is a 'disguised' monadic bind (i.e. `>>=`).

The type of `generalB` (and `generalB2`) is equivalent to `liftM2`, which [is implemented like this](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/src/GHC-Base.html#liftM2):

```
liftM2  :: (Monad m) => (a1 -> a2 -> r) -> m a1 -> m a2 -> m r
liftM2 f m1 m2 = do { x1 <- m1; x2 <- m2; return (f x1 x2) }
```

That is, in terms of `return` and `>>=` (which you don't see, because it's using `do` syntax).

Comment: Well, but the point is that, as I wrote in the first comment to the code, the `(>>=)` operator is hidden, therefore the `do` notation is not available. Indeed the last topic (after this one for which I ask help) is about the `do` notation.

Comment: @Enlico Looking through the comments, it looks like you arrived at an answer in the meantime?

Comment: Well, in a way the answer is in yours, just that `do` is not available and needs desugaring.

Comment: @Enlico Indeed. I wasn't sure if you wanted a hint, or a full solution.